# Recommendations for a React component that prioritizes children and only allows one to render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, higher-order-components

Looking to make a type of "manager" parent component that can take an arbitrary number of children that may render as `null` (no more than a dozen or so max, probably less so scale isn't required), determine which will render and is the most important to render, and then *just* render that one. So for instance, if the component were declared as follows:

```
<ChildManager>
    <ChildA priority={1} [...someOtherProps]/>
    <ChildB priority={3} [...someOtherProps]/>
    <ChildC priority={2} [...someOtherProps]/>
</ChildManager>
```

where `ChildB` would render as null due to some interior component logic, it would just render `ChildC` as it has the highest priority value.

I got a basic version of this working though the solution I have feels pretty anti-pattern/hacky. Essentially I have each child render as `null` initially but call on a shared `iWillRender` callback prop with what it would render and what that priority is. The manager then collects these callbacks and uses them to determine which child to render.

The only other approach I can think of would be to have the `ChildManager` contain *all* the conditional render logic and associated data for every possible child which feels much messier and less extendable if future children need to be added. I'd love a cleaner solution where some kind of child pattern can be copy-pasted to quickly make a new child component which ties back into the manager. Perhaps a higher order component which wraps each child and handles the logic there though I don't know how that could possibly tie into a higher level manager which determines which to then solely render?

Comment: Can you give a more practical example of what type of components the children are? like... why would the children ever render `null` if the manager is supposed to determine if they render or not?

Comment: maybe you can post your hacky solution for ChildManager so we can see what your intent is a bit better

Comment: The code's all a bit too big to share plus I don't know if I can. However suffice to say I have a series of banners (the children) which may or may not render on a given page depending. Each fetches it's own data to determine this using a GQL HOC. If the data is missing or doesn't meet certain criteria then they might just render as null.

As I said I could, in theory, simply query all the data necessary to make this determination at the manager level but that feels less extendable and I'd rather allow each banner to determine this independently.